# Preloader delayed

Tags: javascript, delay, preloader

I'm trying to implement a preloader on a site. It's the simplest one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function(){
$('body').addClass('loaded');
}, 750);
});
```

It's working pretty nicely, but when you load the page for the first time it actually takes some more time for it to disappear, which ruins the text fade in effect on landing page.

You can see the page live preview here: [LIVE](http://www.jonatancichawa.com)

Does it depend only on Internet speed? I moved the js code all the way up, it loads as the first element. I can't find a solution to this.

(you can get a "fresh first time loading" by opening a new incognito tab every time)

Comment: link looks ok to me...

Comment: Guess it may depend on Internet speed then.

Comment: Could not sure what you mean by your problem... If I understand correctly, make it so that it starts the fade in effect only once the time is up. Ie: after the spinner. Make the fade dependant on when the spinner is done, not X time after the page has loaded

Comment: Yeah, seems like I will have to tweak it this way, with some javascript adding fading classes after spinner in done, instead of making it the easiest way with X time. Thanks for checking it out! I appreciate it :)